# How to change DatePicker Header color in dark mode using MaterialCalendar?

Tags: android, xml, datepicker, android-theme, android-dark-theme

The code below is style **(in light mode)** for my DatePicker

```
<style name="datePickerCustomStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/lc4</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/lc3</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/lc4</item>
        <item name="background">@color/lc3</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/lc3</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/lc4</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/TEXT</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/TEXT</item>
    </style>
```

And this one **(in dark mode)** for my DatePicker

```
    <style name="datePickerCustomStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/dc4</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/dc3</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/dc4</item>
        <item name="background">@color/dc3</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/dc3</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/dc4</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/TEXT</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/TEXT</item>
    </style>
```

I get this solution

[image]

And I obviously call this in this code

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(HomeActivity.this,R.style.datePickerCustomStyle ,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }
                        },year,month,day);
                        datePickerDialog.show();
```

I just wanna know how do I make the ***Header my choice of color in Dark mode?***